# Man AT Ubuntu как запускать при старте ОС?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

Установил at на ubuntu, но при тестах не работает, его надо как-то запустить демона, но я не знаю как это сделать?

Comment: запускать/останавливать/включать/отключать — как и любой другой сервис. единственный нюанс — сервис называется `atd`, а не `at` (так называется программа для взаимодействия с сервисом).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo systemctl enable --now atd
```